# Cut a special char in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Someone know how to cut a string with a SPLIT Method ?

> No idea when it comes with  ' \ '.

```
**identitiname = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
identitiname  *// it has the value  FAMILY\ANDRES*
string[] usuario = identitiname.Split( '\' );**
```

It gives me an error code.

Regards

Comment: string[] usuario = identitiname.Split( '\\' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we split string by \ then you have to use \\ because \ is used for formatting..

```
   string[] usuario = identitiname.Split( '\\' );
```

Comment: Thanks.
easier than i thought